# How can we set margins programatically for Relative-layout in android

Tags: android

Hi i am very `begginer` for android and i have added Relative layout programatically on my blank Activity and so for everything is ok

Here my main requirement is i would like to set margins for that Relative-layout at four sides for this i have tried some code but that's not working please help me

### my code:-

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Creating a new RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);


        setContentView(ll);
}
```

Comment: do you need to do this programatically? Why not use xml..

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setLayoutParams()` after setting your margins:

```
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        ll.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);// here
        setContentView(ll);
```

PS: In your case, it's better if you set your `RelativeLayout` from xml

Answer (score -1):

Just in case that you need it in XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dip">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you could set them by one

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
```

And so on